# How to initialize variable in viewDidLoad() Swift2

Tags: ios, swift2

I am trying to create a stopWatch app as a part of learning swift. Coming from Java I am having a hard time figuring out how to initialize a variable. Relevant code of viewcontroller:

```
var timerRunning = false

var timer: NSTimer = NSTimer() //first initialization I want to remove this initialization and leave it as nil


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
// second initialization
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.timeChanged), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func timeChanged(){
    print("1 second")
}
```

The problem I am facing is double initialization of the **timer** variable which I think is redundant and cannot set to nil. My goal is to use timer variable in a couple of functions and initialize it on a button pressed event. The above approach works but I am looking for some cleaner/correct implementations.
Thank You

Comment: You can change `var timer: NSTimer = NSTimer()` to `var timer: NSTimer!`, this way mean your timer should always have a value or `var timer: NSTimer?` if it can be nil and can be set to nil later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your timer variable as optional so that initially it will have `nil` value and later on you can instantiate it on button event.